# In how may languages UITextchecker is possible for spell check?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my application i am detecting that submitted word is correct or not & for that i am using UITextChecker & now i am developing that app for more than one languages 
Does any one knows how many languages is it possible to check that word is spelled correct or not using UITextChecker?

-Thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following are the languages-
“en_GB”,
“es_ES”,
“fr_FR”,
“it_IT”,
“pt_BR”,
“pt_PT”,
“nl_NL”,
“de_DE”,
“en_CA”,
“ru_RU”,
“en_US”,
“en_AU”,
“sv_SE”,
“da_DK”

But listen to JMax comment also :)

Comment: ok thanx a lot n i'll definitely follow JMAX comment and one more question I have to pass @"en",@"fr" in language string or@“fr_FR”,@"en_GB"?

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 2.0** You can get the list of languages using this code

```
let getAvailableLanguages = UITextChecker.availableLanguages()
print(getAvailableLanguages)
```

Now it is

```
[ru_RU, en_CA, pt_BR, it_IT, ko_KR, nb_NO, de_DE, en_GB, sv_SE, en_AU, en_SG, es_MX, pt_PT, en_IN, fr_FR, es_ES, nl_NL, tr_TR, fi_FI, pl_PL, en_US, da_DK]
```